# Consider function $h : \Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Q$ defined as $h(m,n) = \frac{m}{|n| +1}$.

Tags: functions

Determine whether this is injective and whether it is surjective. This function is not injective because of the unequal elements $(1,2)$ and
$(1,−2)$ in $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ for which $h(1,2) = h(1,−2)$.
What about surjectivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\frac {p}{q} \in Q$

Without loss of generality we may assume that $q>1$

Note that $$h(p,q-1) = \frac {p}{|q-1|+1} =   \frac {p}{q-1+1} =\frac {p}{q}$$

Thus $h$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, the function is not injective. It is surjective, though. For any rational number $\frac{a}{b}$, we can assume that $b$ is positive (why?). Thus, we have that
$$h(a,b-1)=\frac{a}{|b-1|+1}=\frac{a}{b-1+1}=\frac{a}{b}$$